# IBM DB2 Type 4 driver?

Tags: db2

Where can I find the redistributable version of the IBM DB2 Type 4 driver?
I suppose this is the driver I would use to connect from a Java app (on windows) to DB2 on the mainframe?

Answer (score 7):

You will not be able to connect to the mainframe with any redistributable JDBC driver. The driver pack consists of the actual type 4 driver (db2jcc.jar) and any number of license files of the form:

```
 db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar
```

where the `cisuz` bit is variable, indicating the platforms that you're allowed to run on (iSeries, pSeries, System z, LUW and so on).

You're only likely to get `cu` with any freely distributable pack. You need the `z` to access DB2 on the mainframe and that's jealously guarded so you'll need to purchase a specific edition of DB2 Connect to get it. I think both PE and EE, the personal and enterprise editions, have this licence file.

Without that license file, the type 4 driver won't even *try* to talk to the server, you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 5):

[IBM's Fix pack site](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=71&uid=swg21288110) has the "IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ" which is nothing but the JDBC type 4 driver.  Though the page I pointed to above happens to be the windows page, it's the same type 4 driver for all platforms, as should be expected.

I don't think any user/password is required.

Comment: Link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to download the JDBC driver separately it is already shipped with your DB2 product.
You can easily find it at this location : `C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc.jar`

`db2jcc.jar` is the driver name

Answer (score 2):

You can get the drivers from the [IBM site](https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/preLogin.do?lang=en_US&source=swg-idsjs11). You will need to have IBM ID and password to login (which you can obtain [here](https://www.ibm.com/account/profile/us/en?page=reg)). Zip file is about 7 MBs, in contains DB2 9.5 JDBC (type 2/4) and SQLJ drivers. Type 4 drivers are in db2jcc4.jar.
However, you won't be able to connect to mainframes with this driver if mainframe is running DB2 for z/OS. To do so, you need at least to purchase [DB2 Connect](http://www.ibm.com/software/data/db2/db2connect/) product, which will cost you about $500 minimum.

Comment: No db2jcc4.jar is for JDBC 4.0 and Java 6+ while db2jcc.jar is JDBC 3.0 and Java 1.4.2+. db2jcc contains Type2 and Type4 drivers. see http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0051316.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on an AS/400 (or iSeries, or whatever the heck IBM is calling it these days), you'll probably want to get it from [JTOpen](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/).

Their toolbox replaces the old Java Toolbox and includes the JDBC drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If I need any IBM JARs for DB2 or MQ, I usually just add it to the instructions that DB2 or MQ needs to be installed as a prerequisite along with a URL to download it.

The same goes for Java and many other not easily redistributable products as well.

This eliminates the need to worry about licensing issues as it would be on the onus of the user rather than the vendor to obtain the proper licenses.